# Grammar: It takes time to be proficient in a language once you start learning

Tags: grammar, non-native-english

Is it a correct way to say it?

> It takes time to be proficient in a language once you start learning.

Or does it sound awkward?

What about this:

> It takes time to be proficient in a language once starting to learn it.

If none of these sounds natural, what would be the natural way to say it? Assuming that you guys understand what I'm trying to say here.

Comment: _It takes time to become proficient in a language_ is clear, concise and sufficient to express your idea.

Comment: The first one is OK. The second one is ungrammatical; *_once starting to learn it_ is not a correct construction. The final adverb phrase _once you start learning_ would be better fronted, with a comma: _Once you start learning, it takes time to be proficient in a language._

Comment: If you wish to become proficient in English, please carefully read the objectives of this site and ask yourself whether it is the right place to ask questions of this sort, or whether English Language Learners is where you should be.

Comment: Both sentences are grammatical. (I disagree with an earlier comment; the second sentence is only quite unusual.) However, a more idiomatic sentence would be a hybrid of the two: *It takes time to be proficient in a language once you start (learning / to learn) it.*